# in outlook 2007 I get a stop sign besides some contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have this stop sign besides some contacts so I am afraid that they don't get my email.

[image: Stop sign beside contact]

I checked the Safe Receipts and the list is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a smart tag indicates their online status.

It could be people that are on your Windows Live Messenger contact list but are currently blocked (for IM). Note that when you appear offline in Messenger, it basically just sets you in "block everyone" mode.